# How do I remove the default City in Jobs/Careers.SE

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm trying to remove Sydney as the default? it doesn't have an X to delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck *always include your current location* found right above where it says *Sidney, New South Wales, Australia*.

The reason why that's your default, is because you selected it as such, in your developer story.

Comment: Sydney isn't my current location, but this looks like it will work

Comment: Yes, my developer story. I was thinking it was linked to my SO profile. Thanks for clearing things up.